# What will happen if we have false condition and Ref in CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have this CloudFormation configuration:

```
Resources:
  DevoSnsTopic:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
    Condition: UseDevoTopic
    ...
  SnsTopic:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
    ...
  QueuePolicy:
    Properties:
       Condition:
          'ForAnyValue:ArnEquals':
             'aws:SourceArn':
               - Ref: SnsTopic
               - Ref: DevoSnsTopic
```

Will it break if `UseDevoTopic` equals `false`? Or it will simply skip reference for `DevoSnsTopic`?

UPD: Yes missing resource breaks the changeset!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're concerned with an invalid reference if the `UseDevoTopic` is false and `DevoSnsTopic` hasn't been created, you could use the `Fn::If` condition and provide the  [`AWS::NoValue`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/pseudo-parameter-reference.html) Pseudo Parmater if false

```
Resources:
  DevoSnsTopic:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
    Condition: UseDevoTopic
    ...
  SnsTopic:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
    ...
  QueuePolicy:
    Properties:
       Condition:
          'ForAnyValue:ArnEquals':
             'aws:SourceArn':
               - Ref: SnsTopic
               - !If [UseDevoTopic, !Ref DevoSnsTopic, AWS::NoValue]
```

Answer (score 0):

A resource is only created if the `Condition` evaluates to true. It it is not true, then the resource will not be created.

This is a great way to deploy different resources (or resources with different attributes) between Dev/Test/Prod systems, or to do some if/then logic for specifying values.

Here's some snippets from a CloudFormation template that deploys differently based upon the region in which it is deployed:

```
"Conditions": {
    "InUsEast1": {
      "Fn::Equals": [
        {
          "Ref": "AWS::Region"
        },
        "us-east-1"
      ]
    },
```

Comment: I understand this, so in my case DevoSnsTopic won't be created and QueuePolicy will only process messages from SnsTopic correct?

Comment: Yes, sounds correct. However, the template might fail to build due to the reference from `QueuePolicy` to `DevoSnsTopic` (if the condition is false). You'd have to try it to find out what happens.